# Can flutter move widgets using a controller?

Tags: flutter, dart, input, remote-access, remote-server

I'm planning to make an app with features that the creator can move ?, like touchpad input or mouse/keyboard input,

I have tried some kind of xdotool but it only works on linux and even then it uses native executable binary,

so can flutter move the app like remote team viewer but only the app itself using darts? Sorry, I'm a programming beginner

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Draggable class for dragging the item which you want to drag and for placing it or sticking it somewhere on the screen you have to wrap that item with DragTarget class. In the DragTarget class onAccept method is there where you can write the logic.